# How do you automatically start a WAS server on machine reboot?

Tags: windows, websphere, autostart

I'm running a WebSphere Application Server 8 environment under Windows 2008 Server R2 and I've installed a test environment for some software I'm developing.

However, on reboot, I have to manually start the server each time using:

```
Start
|
+-- IBM WepSphere
    |
    +-- IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5
        |
        +-- Profiles
            |
            +-- MyProfile
                |
                +-- Start the server
```

which is a bit of a pain, almost as much a pain as typing in that monstrosity above :-)

Once the server is running, you can automate starting of the applications *within* it by using the admin console for that server and setting startup order, but I can see no configuration for starting the *server/profile* itself.

In fact, I can see no WebSphere-wide programs (ie, non-profile related) to run other than the configuration migrator and profile manager - the latter lists the profile I'm using but doesn't seem to allow any configuration of it, the only button seeming to be for creating a *new* profile.

How can I automate the starting of the server so I don't have to go through those steps each time? And how can this be done in a way that doesn't require anyone to log in to the box itself each time to get it to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**WASService command**](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Fae%2Frins_wasservice.html) in order to setup WAS as a Windows service.